# Why do the values not change in an Array after processing in for.Each?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reference

I have 4 different values (strings) in JavaScript. I need to make a check, if one of these values is not a number. If so, then replace the value with "---", if not, do nothing. So I put the values in an array and called the forEach-function to check. So I actually want my predefined variables (before putting them in an array) to change if they are not a number, but only the elements of the array change.

So I did some researches and I found the difference between call-by-reference and call-by-value. So I changed my variables to String-Objects, but it does not work.
I know, hat calling the elements of my array would also work, but I want to understand why my actual variables does not change
?

```
    var first = new String("1");
    var second = new String("2");
    var third = new String("3");
    var fourth = new String("test");

    var testArr = [first, second, third, fourth];
    testArr.forEach(function (value, index) {
        if (isNaN(value)) {
            this[index] = "---";
        }
    }, testArr);

    console.log(fourth);
    //*here I expect "---" but it is "test"*
    //I know that testArr[3] is now "---", but why not the variable fourth as well?
```

Comment: The array contains copies of references to your String objects. Changing the array properties won't change the variables. Try `console.log(testArr)` if you want to see what the array contains.

Comment: in this case of your code, values are just argument of a function

Comment: Also it's extremely rare that String object values are needed in JavaScript, as opposed to string primitive values. Using them can lead to weird hard-to-find bugs.

Comment: @Pointy: How can I change the variables because I want to work with them in the further Script and not with the annoying testArr[index] notation. I don't want for each vaiable to make a If-statement,.

Comment: You can't change the variables that way. That's not how JavaScript works. Use an object with named properties instead of variables if you want to access them by computed name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Value stored in variables will never be changed, because in your case variable host value itself, not reference. If you want to apply this kind of magic, you should:

1. Put initial values in array/object
2. Use objects instead of typed variables e.g:

   ```
   var first = {value:'1'};
   var second = {value:'2'};
   var third = {value:'3'};
   var fourth = {value:'replaceme'};

   var testArr = [first, second, third, fourth];
   testArr.forEach(function (obj, index) {
       if (isNaN(obj.value)) {
           obj.value = "---";
       }
   });

   console.log(fourth);
   ```

Comment: You completely missed the second argument in the `forEach` method, as well as the use of `this` in his loop.

Comment: @Morphyish so what ? effect remains the same

Comment: So is this the best way to solve my problem or is there a shorter way?

Comment: look at your updated code, it doesn't make sense to have the `testArr` argument ?

Comment: Exactly, as well as that one posted by TS =)

Comment: If there is no point in using arr, why TS would do that? he wants to iterate through random variables, but groups them as he likes. And have a small benefit of gaining forEach to loop

Comment: this argument `}, testArr);` isn't making sense if you are no longer using `this` in your function. He was using `this`, you are not, you should remove it.

Comment: Yes, anyone could find your answer. It doesn't cost you anything to actually make sure that you are not leaving anything that could be confusing for no reason.